# LG TV is detected on one Windows 10 and is not on second

Tags: windows-10, tv, miracast

Both computers support Miracast.

From first (my work laptop) I am able to connect to the TV as remote display:

(Wireless Card - Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM0pO.png)

But from the second PC I dont see the TV.

(Wireless Card - Realtek 8822CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCE-E NIC)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPGhq.png)

I have all drivers up to date. Tried to disable fully Firewall and antivirus. PC is also set as discoverable.

Altough I can cast screen, but I can right click video file -> cast on device, there the TV is visible.

I might be just missing something. Does anybody know what can be wrong?

Laptop that doesnt see the TV has this wireless card:

Thanks.

Comment: Are the computers connected to the same (home) network using the same type of connection (LAN, WiFi, ...)?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, all 3 devices are on the same WiFi network

Comment: I suggest editing the question to add both WiFi cards. The difference must be on the hardware.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I did add the wireless card info

Comment: Your second image looks totally different from the first one - why is that? Please translate the text so we can read it.

Comment: @harrymc It was just to demonstrate, that on the second PC the Filipovi TV is not showing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows update to 21H1 fixed the issue.

Comment: Please accept your own answer.

Comment: @Gantendo Well you should know there is 24hours delay before I can accept it

Comment: I have never asked a question on this website so I did not know that.